# Does there exist a series with property $n\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} u_{nk}=1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Shortly, the idea is to find such series which admits "lazy" calculation: 
instead of computing all the terms, it would be enough 

 to calculate its even terms (the case with $n=2$), and then multiply result by $2$; 

or calculate third of its terms (the case with $n=3$), and then multiply result by $3$; etc.

It seems that we can construct such series for finite set of values $n$ (say, for $n\in\{1,2,4,8\}$ or $n \in \{1,2,3,4\}$).

So, my **Question** is: does there exist a series 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} u_{k}=1,$$
such that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$n\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} u_{nk}=1. \quad (?) \tag{1}$$

Comment: Knowing the series, you could be even lazier and just write $1$ for the series than calculate anything ...